# Combining two different queries

Tags: mysql

I have two queries that select similar columns, but have different `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses. I need to combine these two queries with `UNION` so that in total it shows 26 results (combined), sorted by date. I have no idea how I would do this with the following two queries.

First query:

```
SELECT p.post_id,
       p.reply_to,
       p.parent_id,
       p.post_path,
       p.user_id,
       p.content,
       p.datetime,
       p.total_likes,
       p.total_replies,
       p.total_reposts,
       u.username,
       u.display_name,
       l.like_id,
       l.user_id
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes l ON (l.post_id = p.post_id AND l.user_id = ?)
WHERE p.user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ?)
AND p.removed != 1
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC LIMIT 26
```

Second query:

```
SELECT p.post_id,
       p.reply_to,
       p.parent_id,
       p.post_path,
       p.user_id,
       p.content,
       p.datetime,
       p.total_likes,
       p.total_replies,
       p.total_reposts,
       u.username,
       u.display_name,
       l.like_id,
       l.user_id
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE l.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM likes WHERE user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ? AND following_id != ?))
AND l.user_id != p.user_id AND p.removed != 1
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC LIMIT 26
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Do they have the same set of columns returning?  Looks to me like it does.  Just drop 'UNION' (for removing dups) or 'UNION ALL` between the two selects.

Comment: just use union all as andrew said and use `ORDER BY p.datetime DESC LIMIT 26`at the end of query just make sure it is used once at the end

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put a UNION or UNION ALL between the two select statements. Also, make sure you remove the first ORDER BY, that will throw an error. The below statement should run.

```
SELECT p.post_id,
       p.reply_to,
       p.parent_id,
       p.post_path,
       p.user_id,
       p.content,
       p.datetime,
       p.total_likes,
       p.total_replies,
       p.total_reposts,
       u.username,
       u.display_name,
       l.like_id,
       l.user_id
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes l ON (l.post_id = p.post_id AND l.user_id = ?)
WHERE p.user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ?)
AND p.removed != 1
UNION
SELECT p.post_id,
       p.reply_to,
       p.parent_id,
       p.post_path,
       p.user_id,
       p.content,
       p.datetime,
       p.total_likes,
       p.total_replies,
       p.total_reposts,
       u.username,
       u.display_name,
       l.like_id,
       l.user_id
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE l.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM likes WHERE user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ? AND following_id != ?))
AND l.user_id != p.user_id AND p.removed != 1
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC LIMIT 26
```

Comment: I get an error `Trying to get property of non-object` on this line in PHP: `if ($stmt->num_rows) {`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use UNION . try this

```
SELECT   
  (SELECT p.post_id,
     p.reply_to,
     p.parent_id,
     p.post_path,
     p.user_id,
     p.content,
     p.datetime,
     p.total_likes,
     p.total_replies,
     p.total_reposts,
     u.username,
     u.display_name,
     l.like_id,
     l.user_id
  FROM posts p 
  LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
  LEFT JOIN likes l ON (l.post_id = p.post_id AND l.user_id = ?)
  WHERE p.user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ?)
  AND p.removed != 1
  ORDER BY p.datetime DESC LIMIT 26)

UNION

 (SELECT p.post_id,
      p.reply_to,
      p.parent_id,
      p.post_path,
      p.user_id,
      p.content,
      p.datetime,
      p.total_likes,
      p.total_replies,
      p.total_reposts,
      u.username,
      u.display_name,
      l.like_id,
      l.user_id
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE l.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM likes WHERE user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM   follows WHERE user_id = ? AND following_id != ?))
AND l.user_id != p.user_id AND p.removed != 1
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC LIMIT 26)
```

Comment: You can also use it without a subselect

Comment: The question asks for 26 combined results. The `LIMIT` should be at the end, as posted in other answers.

Comment: I get an error `Trying to get property of non-object` on this line in PHP: `if ($stmt->num_rows) {`.

Answer (score 0):

If the selected columns have compatible types, just put them together with `UNION`. I understand you want to put the `LIMIT`at the end to apply it to the complete query:

```
 SELECT p.post_id,
   p.reply_to,
   p.parent_id,
   p.post_path,
   p.user_id,
   p.content,
   p.datetime,
   p.total_likes,
   p.total_replies,
   p.total_reposts,
   u.username,
   u.display_name,
   l.like_id,
   l.user_id
FROM posts p 
   LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
   LEFT JOIN likes l ON (l.post_id = p.post_id AND l.user_id = ?)
WHERE p.user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ?)
   AND p.removed != 1
UNION
SELECT p.post_id,
   p.reply_to,
   p.parent_id,
   p.post_path,
   p.user_id,
   p.content,
   p.datetime,
   p.total_likes,
   p.total_replies,
   p.total_reposts,
   u.username,
   u.display_name,
   l.like_id,
   l.user_id
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE l.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM likes WHERE user_id IN 
          (SELECT following_id FROM follws WHERE user_id = ? AND following_id != ?))
    AND l.user_id != p.user_id AND p.removed != 1
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC LIMIT 26
```

Comment: I get an error `Trying to get property of non-object` on this line in PHP: `if ($stmt->num_rows) {`.